# How can I discover the keys used in a C# indexer?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

We have a legacy class that uses an indexer to allow people to add arbitrary key-value pairs:

```
legacyInstance["myKey"] = value;
```

Sadly, we can't look at or modify the code for this class.  We can only access it through its various properties.

What we need to do is clone this object in an intelligent way.  Normal properties are simple to clone, of course:

```
myClone.blargle = legacyInstance.blargle;
```

But how do we discover all of the keys that someone may have added to a particular object instance in order to clone them correctly?  Ideally something like this:

```
string[] keys = legacyInstance.<#magic!#>;
foreach (string key in keys)
{
    myClone[key] = legacyInstance[key];
}
```

And while I suspect the magic may involve some Reflection, getting at it is proving difficult since I am a Reflection tyro.

Comment: You can't. What if the data were stored in a database? How would reflection help you with that?

Comment: First step is to look at an instance of legacyInstance in the Debugger and poke around the properties it has.  If you can find one that has the keys you're looking for then you can use reflection to access it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders : Excellent point.  I had a generalized bad feeling about this, but I was spending too much time looking at Reflection documentation, and not enough time thinking at what could be going on behind the scenes.  Your comment makes the base issue fairly clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) and get into sources. If your collection doesn't expose members to iterate over keys (like `Dictionary` exposes `Keys`) then this is your only option. By the way, may be you collection is `IEnumerable`? Actually it is strange for a collection not to provide **any** iteration facilities. Is not it called `YouCanOnlyUseIndexCollection`?